# Message as 'undefined' in protractor html screenshot reporter

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I am getting 'undefined' in the message section of the generated html report of Protractor-Html-Screenshot reporter. In my tests i am using chai.assert. It should ideally give 'Passed' for passed scripts.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Even i have noticed the same. It only happens when i have multiple 'it' in my describe function. Otherwise it works fine, though that's not a solution!

Answer (score 0):

@mainak and @js2892. That is because you did not have a expect statement for the particular "it" block. If you add a expect then the result of message will be pass.

Comment: i am using the assert instead of expect.So that shall not work?!